Trying to bake normal maps but all are solid purple (no details)
I have a high and low poly versions of an ak-47 I made. I'm now trying to bake the normal map from the high poly model. The problem is that the normal map is just solid purple, and it doesn't contain any details. I'm wondering if this is expected, or if I'm doing something wrong.
my render setting is cycles.
For all different parts of the ak-47, the normal map is solid purple:


Do the meshes look like these normal maps are expected? i.e is it that they just don't contain enough deformation or something.

Your material setup is correct!
But, you need to set your object locations in same place
Here is as example for suzanne model high an low poly versions locations

As you can see they are inside each other.
After that set bake settings like this

If done correctly all you need is just that.
but lets add an example material node setup

Create new material in properties/material or shader editor panels

Add new "Image Texture" node

Click to new button on "Image Texture" node


And you are ready!

Don't forget to select that newly created node before pressing bake button on properties panel!
Our export looks like that for this setup.

